# Send signal to process from command line

Tags: linux, signals

I read about signals and I know how to send a signal to a process from the command line. Just do

```
ps -C executable
```

to know the pid of the process, and then

```
kill -s signal pid(number)
```

However, I'd like to find a more interactive and general way to do this if possible.

I'd like to send a signal to a specific process from the command line. I'd like to not need to print the PID of the process I want to signal, but rather use a way that the code understands which process should be signaled.

Other than that I'd like to understand exacly what the kill command does.

- Does it kill the process that signals?
- Does it kill the process where it's called?
- If it kills a process it means that it's similar to do `exit(0)`, or does the process resume after the signal is sent back?

Comment: So what would be you *desired* form of sending signal? Can you specify it by an example?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd say a command that would run a function in the code would be perfect. I'd be abble to create a function to send the signal without a problem. I'd still want to know what kill does though

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I understood your question you want to signal a process by its name, not by its PID. This can easily be achieved by combining the two commands:

```
kill -s signal $(ps -C executable)
```

> Does it kill the process that signals?

`kill` **can** kill. It doesn't necessarily.

From `man kill`:

> The  command kill sends the specified signal to the specified
>   processes
>          or process groups.

That means, the `kill` command is used to **send any signal in general.

> If it kills a process it means that it's similar to do `exit(0)`, or
>   does the process resume after the signal is sent back?

From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html):

> The `SIGKILL` signal is used to cause immediate program termination. It
>   cannot be handled or ignored, and is therefore always fatal. It is
>   also not possible to block this signal.

If a process receives the `SIGKILL` signal, it terminates immediately (no destructors called, no cleanup done). The only processes that do not terminate are uninterruptible processes.

---

A full list of signals available on Linux is found [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Comment: so I can use kill without a problem, and it will not pause or kill any process, as long as I don't use the SIGKILL signal?

Comment: However, I have 3 processes, so I think your answer proposal would send the signal to all 3 of them, not 1 specific

Comment: @AndréAlmeida `kill` only sends signals. There are other signals such as `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTERM`, which stop/terminate programs. You need to look each signal's function up to be sure what it does.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this:

```
pkill -signal processname
```

Here is a concrete example I use from time to time:

```
pkill -USR1 Squeak
```

See [pkill - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to send a signal to a specific proccess from the command line. I'd like to not need to print the PID of the process I want to signal, but rather use a way that the code understands which process should be signaled.

The `killall` command meets those criteria, if you have it available to you.  It allows you to specify the process(es) to signal based on their names.  All of the following comments apply equally to the effects of delivering a signal via `killall` and delivering one via `kill`.

> Other than that I'd like to understand exacly what the kill command does.
>
> Does it kill the process that signals?

It delivers the specified signal.  That's it.  Some signals it can deliver will have the effect of killing the process.

> Does it kill the process where it's called?

It delivers a signal only to the process you specify.

> If it kills a process it means that it's similar to do exit(0), or does the process resume after the signal is sent back?

Processes can handle some signals without terminating.  Exactly what happens when a process receives one of those signals depends on the process.  If a process does not provide a handler for a signal whose default action is to terminate the process, then the process will die, never to resume.  The effect is somewhat like that of calling the `exit()` function or returning from `main()`, but the termination is abrupt, without calling exit handlers or such.